# How to show this Sobolev space is a uniformly convex space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

From the book by Kufner:[image]

How do I prove this theorem? I'd like to do it using the epsilon delta definition (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_space) if possible.

Comment: @Tomás a weight is a.e positive and is measurable. That space you wanted defining is the space of all functions $f$ with $fw_\alpha^{\frac 1 p} \in L^p$. I have this from the book.

Comment: I have posted a answer. Please give me the name of this book of Kufner. @soup it is the Kufner book?

Comment: @Tomás it's from http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VUg6dcsLRDQC&source=gbs_navlinks_s. It's the same book.

Comment: @Tomás It's Quasilinear Elliptic Equations With Degenerations and Singularities, the same one that soup linked. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that $W^{k,p}(\Omega,w)$ is a Banach space when $(1.13)$ is satisfied, you can see [here](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/106324) in this paper of Kufner. There, he also shows that the condition $(1.13)$ is necessary. The big motivation for such condition is the fact that if it is satisfied, then $L^p(\Omega, w_\alpha)$ is continuously embedded in $L^1(\Omega)$ (with the usual measure).

To prove the uniformly convexity of $W^{k,p}(\Omega,w)$, you can use this same [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216321/is-sobolev-spaces-uniformly-convex), which works because $L^P(\Omega,w_\alpha)$ is uniformly convex (see [Brezis](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uni.wroc.pl%2F~karch%2Fanaliza_nieliniowa%2Fref%2FBREZIS__Functional_Analysis__Sobolev_Spaces_and_Partial_Differential_Equations__Universitext_.pdf&ei=_Vw7Usm3K5Oa8wT2z4GgCA&usg=AFQjCNGP9nqQmNf4F1EOrBbb_glm25twWQ&sig2=zxjHG9i5FuO317qUu41X1A) page 95, Theorem 4.10 and Remarkk 3).

To give a proof by using delta and epsilon definition, you can take, for example, the proof given by Brezis and apply the isometry.